# Xamarin Android not working properly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Whenever I create a xamarin Android blank App project then add widgets ( views ) in the program and run it using visual studio emulator I get the app and everything but empty without any widgets, it was working properly two days ago and I haven't changed anything, I have tried different versions of xamarin and jdk but nothing worked. what can I do to fix such a problem?

Comment: post code to your main activity

Comment: there's no need for code i do it using the designer and i don't edit the main code becauae i don't want any behaviour i just want to test the design , and with the pre created project that comes when you open xamarin

Comment: did you try to uninstall the app from your emulator and running it again? Could be that it's being cached

Comment: i did try that yes and i stil have the same problem

Comment: Did you uncomment `SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);` in `MainActivity.cs`?  It is commented out by default.

Comment: yes i did, i also tried to findResources by id and they showup in code fine, i even tried to set the visibility to visible but nothing changed